# Values in nav_msgs/Odometry.msg corresponds to orientation

Tags: ros, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am implementing the sampling algorithm (sample_motion_model_odometry) from Thrun's Probabilisitic Robotics book p. 136, which samples the current pose of a robot using odometry information.

I am wanting to test my implementation, and have access to a rosbag which has nav_msgs/Odometry.msg. However I am struggling to identify which column in this message would correspond to the odometry frame orientation theta. Any help in the matter would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269538/values-in-nav_msgs/odometry.msg-corresponds-to-orientation/) by [apples92](https://answers.ros.org/users/31596/apples92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: there is no column in the message that *immediately* corresponds to the odometry frame orientation theta.

Long answer: ROS messages can be similar to Russian nesting dolls in that they are composed of messages, which are composed of messages, which are composed of messages, etc. So, sometimes it takes some digging to get to the information that you're looking for.

According to the [api](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html), the `nav_msgs/Odometry` is structured as follows:

```
# This represents an estimate of a position and velocity in free space.  
# The pose in this message should be specified in the coordinate frame given by header.frame_id.
# The twist in this message should be specified in the coordinate frame given by the child_frame_id
Header header
string child_frame_id
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose
geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance twist
```

The orientation is buried within the pose attribute of the message which is of the type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance`. If you go to the api that I linked to and keep clicking the links that are listed under the **Compact Message Definition** section you'll eventually find that the orientation is given as a `geometry_msgs/Quaternion`.

The [`geometry_msgs/Quaternion` api](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Quaternion.html) shows that the orientation is given as a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) (the name also gives that away too). For information on how to use quaternions, see [this tutorial from the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Tutorials/Quaternions) and [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/9981/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them/).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1